# Change in directory for FatFree framework does not work

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I have started to learn the F3 framework (PHP) and I have gotten the Hello World program running.

However, I am facing a problem which is simple but I can't seem to get what am I doing wrong. When I keep the `index.php` file on the web root directory(/var/www) with the routing as -

```
F3::route('GET /', 'home);
```

and access `http://localhost`, I am getting the correct output. However, if I place the index.php file on the path `/var/www/my_test/` and change the routing as follows-

```
F3::route('GET /my_test/', 'home')
```

and access `http://localhost/my_test/` I get that the URL does not exist.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you have been able to figure this out but if not, I hope I can help.

The `.htaccess` file is what points to the `index.php` page.  If you change the location of the `index.php` file, you will need to modify your `.htaccess`.  This is only if you change *just* the location of the `index.php`.

If you move the entire contents to a subfolder, I believe that folder becomes the BASE.  So if you put the entire framework into `/var/www/my_test/` then `/my_test/` is the BASE and anything after that slash will be processed by the framework.  `http://localhost/my_test/` will be routed by using `F3::route('GET /','home');` and `http://localhost/my_test/abc` will be routed by using `F3::route('GET /abc','abc');`.

You *may* still have to modify the `.htaccess` file for the folder, but I am not sure.  On my computer, I created a virtual host so I could play around with it.  Good luck!